# AWS EC2: adding IP from a separate private block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an existing VPC with a CIDR in the `10.0.0.0/16` block.

I now have to create a VPN connection to an external service, who want us to use IPs in `192.168.0.0/16` block.

Unfortunately, [AWS does not allow mixing these two blocks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-cidr-blocks.html#add-cidr-block-restrictions) in a single VPC, otherwise adding a new CIDR block would have been an easy solution.

Short of creating a new VPC and migrating services, what are the options to achieve this? Ideally with no additional costs.

Thanks

/edit to add link

Comment: One option is to add an additional CIDR range to your VPC or set up another VPC, then  set up a proxy in the new subnet. I suspect there are many other solutions but that's the first one that comes to mind https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc-now-allows-customers-to-expand-their-existing-vpcs/

Comment: What type of proxy? Any links would be appreciated.

AWS does not allow adding "CIDR blocks from other RFC 1918 ranges". Question updated with link.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting that you can't add two of that type of block, never tried that. Proxy type depends what you're trying to achieve, you've not given much detail.

Comment: All I was trying to do was just add another site-to-site VPN.
Ended up migrating to a new VPC, but surely, there must be an easier way.

Comment: The requirement for a specific CIDR range inside your VPC from whoever you're peering with is unusual. What I would've done would've depended on the peering reason. e.g. If you simply needed to access a web service you could put in another small VPC with an Apache proxy.

Comment: If the VPN client is on an EC2 instance, VPC doesn't know about it, so it can use whatever address you want. (If the VPC can be directly connected to a VPN - is that a thing? then of course it does matter)